# Where do I find MacOS graphics drivers?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mac-mini, graphics, driver

I have a Mac Mini running MacOS 10.13.6, with an Intel HD Graphics 3000 384 MB graphics card. Google Chrome isn't recognizing the graphics drivers as usable for WebGL. See: 
[WebGL disabled or unavailable on Chrome / MacOS](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/chrome/co6w-9D1ZWo;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/authorid$3AAPn2wQcvp61bGi1H23MWUCpNvEs8iOPt3a-01tpY6AlaDZz8JiKNfpWfDfjZenOlck-hixeGZv58%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false)

According to Google, I should update my graphics card drivers. I can't find MacOS-compatible drivers on Intel's site: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81500 How do I update graphics drivers on MacOS?

Comment: There are no newer drivers than the ones built into your OS.

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213892/why-doesnt-os-x-require-graphics-card-driver-updates/213893#213893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel® Graphics Drivers for Mac*
Last Reviewed: 27-Jun-2017
Article ID: 000022440

If you are looking for graphics drivers for a Mac*, we recommend that you visit one of the following Apple* web sites:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201541

https://support.apple.com/choose-country-region/downloads

**Note**        The graphics drivers are built into the Mac operating system; updating to the latest OS release will install the latest drivers.

Comment: Thank you, but your links are broken.

Comment: ok, let me fix that