# Does MacOS automatically update System Drivers?

Tags: macos, mac, driver

Does MacOS automatically update System Drivers? If so, how do I check if they're up to date?

Comment: Related - though somewhat out of date now, as Apple don't use 3rd party GPUs since the move to Aople Silicon- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213892/why-doesnt-os-x-require-graphics-card-driver-updates

Answer (score 2):

If you're on the latest OS, you'll have the latest drivers. You can't generally download and update them separately. And how much they vary between OSes is generally an unknown quantity.

Apple make the software and the hardware, so there's a smaller pool of devices to drive, and they've either written it themselves or licensed code from Qualcom, Intel or AMD, with any alterations they make on top. Either way, it all just goes into the OS.

In over 25 years of using Macs, I can't recall an occasion where a problem was caused by someone not having up-to-date Apple-supplied drivers. *(Third-party drivers for additional hardware, sure.)*